# A method from a library is swallowing an exception that I would like to catch

Tags: java, exception

I am using the class FutureTask that takes a Callable object in his constructor and calls call() from inside his run method like this:

```
public void run() { //Thread
    while(true) {
        try {
            FutureTask<String> task = taskQueue.take();
            task.run(); //executing call() somehow
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread finishing from interrupt()...");
            break; //I would like to break the loop if I receive the exception
        }
    }
}
```

My call implementation is like this:

```
@Override
public String call() throws InterruptedException {
  Thread.sleep(taskTime);
  //After calling interrupt() on this thread an InterruptedException is thrown
  return "someString"; // this is not reached
}
```

But I think that the run method is swallowing the exception since I can not reach the catch block. Do you have any ideas?

I call `thread.interrupt();` with thread being the thread running run().

To be cleared: when `task.run()` is running, it is executing `Thread.sleep(taskTime);` which correctly throws the exception, but the `run()` method seems to swallow it.

**The problem is this: I have a library class (that I can not modify) which takes an object to run a particular method which could throw an exception. This library class acts like a wrapper and it seems like it swallows the exception instead of propagating it. What would you do?**

Comment: Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: I try. I wrote the general problem in bold now.

Comment: Use ..... throw e..... inside the catch block.... which will re throw the exception which can be propagated

Comment: I would've liked to see a complete code example. If you know the library only catches a specific type of exception, you could wrap your exception in a runtime exception and throw that. If the library catches `Exception`, then you are mostly out of luck (unless you want to throw an `Error`, but I don't recommend it.) You could also use a `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Why not handle the exception in the overridden `call` method?

Comment: Can you subclass and override the method with the try/catch?

Comment: Worst case, you might be able to solve this with the Decorator pattern; just wrap the original object in a Decorator that implements the same interface, and pass everything through to the core; but when an exception is thrown, duplicate it at worst and handle it from there.

Comment: I think you are misusing the [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) class. In any case, exceptions thrown while `call` is called are not thrown by `run` but by `get`. Please read the documentation. It would clarify the issue if you add code to your question to show exactly how you use `FutureTask`.

Comment: I edited. I would like to break a loop upon getting the InterruptedException. I can not use get() in my scenario.

Comment: Then you cannot use `FutureTask`. It's not appropriate for this scenario. Why did you choose it?